# How to travers query results and then call the other Stored Procedure in MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, mysql-workbench

Now I can write the separate stored procedure.

```
-- get the total query id result
select id from book where bookprice>10;
-- only pass a single id
call sp_refreshbook(id);
```

How to merge them together?now I want to search the id result and them call the `sp_refreshbook` in each id in the result in a new store  stored procedure.

Comment: show us that `sp_refreshbook` puppy, we can create a new sp_refreshbookLooper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem using cursor by myself.

```
open v_result_cur;
repeat
fetch v_result_cur into v_id;
IF NOT v_done THEN
select v_id; 
END IF;
until v_done end repeat;
close v_result_cur;
```